# Extract text from a large pdf with Tika

Tags: java, pdf, extract, apache-tika

I try to extract text from a large pdf, but i only get the first pages, i need all text to will be passed to a string variable.

This is the code

```
public class ParsePDF {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {


    try {

      File file = new File("C:/vlarge.pdf");

      String content = new Tika().parseToString(file);

      System.out.println("The Content: " + content);

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Q: Exactly how big a string are we talking about?  SUGGESTIONS: 1) You might well have to break your payload into smaller substrings.  2) You might also consider char[] arrays, StringStream or StringBuffer as alteratives.

Comment: My pfd file is aprox 300 pages. I need the content in a string to be processed in different ways, but i dont know whats is the size.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Javadocs](https://tika.apache.org/1.6/api/org/apache/tika/Tika.html#parseToString(java.io.File)):

> To avoid unpredictable excess memory use, the returned string contains
>   only up to getMaxStringLength() first characters extracted from the
>   input document. Use the  setMaxStringLength(int) method to adjust this
>   limitation.

Calling `setMaxStringLength(-1)` will disable this limit.

Answer (score 1):

Try the apache api [TIKA](http://tika.apache.org/). Its working for large PDF's also.

**Sample :**

```
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream("sample.pdf");
        ContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
        new PDFParser().parse(input, handler, metadata, new ParseContext());
        String plainText = handler.toString();
        System.out.println(plainText);
```

Comment: why not just `String fileContent = tika.parseToString(java.io.File file)`