# How to extract text from PDFs using a PIG UDF and Apache Tika?

Tags: apache-pig, apache-tika

I'm attempting to write a PIG eval function (UDF) to extract text from pdf files using Apache Tika. However, my function only writes 0 or 1 bytes to output whenever I try to run the function. How could I fix my code?

```
public class ExtractTextFromPDFs extends EvalFunc<String> {

  @Override
  public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
      String pdfText;

      if (input == null || input.size() == 0 || input.get(0) == null) {
          return "N/A";
      }

      DataByteArray dba = (DataByteArray)input.get(0);
      InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(dba.get());
      ContentHandler contenthandler = new BodyContentHandler();
      Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
      Parser pdfparser = new AutoDetectParser();

      try {
        pdfparser.parse(is, contenthandler, metadata, new ParseContext());
      } catch (SAXException | TikaException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      pdfText = contenthandler.toString();

      //close the input stream
      if(is != null){
        is.close();
      }
      return pdfText;
  }
}
```

I run the code using 'c = foreach b generate ExtractTextFromPDFs(content);' where b is a pdf and content is a bytearray.

Comment: If you step through your code in a debugger, what does the argument "input" look like?

The code you are using looks similar to the code in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20705230/924) stackoverflow answer, the differences being that they use a PDFParser instead of the AutoDetectParser and they are taking things straight from a FileInputStream rather than a Tuple.